# How to validate a Singaporean FIN?

Tags: algorithm, validation

Can anyone provide an algorithm to validate a Singaporean FIN?

I know with a Singaporean NRIC I can validate it via modulo 11 and then compare the result to a lookup table but cannot find a similar lookup table for the FIN.

I also do not know for sure if the modulo 11 is the correct method to validate.

I am aware the government sells a algorithm for $400 but maybe someone knows a cheaper way.

Bonus points for c# implementation.

Comment: i've added a library which contains implementations in several different languages - https://github.com/mjallday/nric-lib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a little searching around I found a way to validate them. This doesn't neccersarily mean the FIN is valid, just that it falls within a valid range.

I based it on algorithms from http://www.ngiam.net/NRIC/ppframe.htm

I've also included a similar method for checking NRIC because I figure anyone who comes across this and is interested in one is interested in the other as well.

Hope this helps someone!

```
    private static readonly int[] Multiples = { 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };

    public static bool IsNricValid(string nric)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nric))
        {
            return false;
        }

        //  check length
        if (nric.Length != 9)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int total = 0
            , count = 0
            , numericNric;
        char first = nric[0]
            , last = nric[nric.Length - 1];

        if (first != 'S' && first != 'T')
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!int.TryParse(nric.Substring(1, nric.Length - 2), out numericNric))
        {
            return false;
        }

        while (numericNric != 0)
        {
            total += numericNric % 10 * Multiples[Multiples.Length - (1 + count++)];

            numericNric /= 10;
        }

        char[] outputs;
        if (first == 'S')
        {
            outputs = new char[] { 'J', 'Z', 'I', 'H', 'G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A' };
        }
        else
        {
            outputs = new char[] { 'G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'J', 'Z', 'I', 'H' };
        }

        return last == outputs[total % 11];

    }

    public static bool IsFinValid(string fin)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fin))
        {
            return false;
        }

        //  check length
        if (fin.Length != 9)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int total = 0
            , count = 0
            , numericNric;
        char first = fin[0]
            , last = fin[fin.Length - 1];

        if (first != 'F' && first != 'G')
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!int.TryParse(fin.Substring(1, fin.Length - 2), out numericNric))
        {
            return false;
        }

        while (numericNric != 0)
        {
            total += numericNric % 10 * Multiples[Multiples.Length - (1 + count++)];

            numericNric /= 10;
        }

        char[] outputs;
        if (first == 'F')
        {
            outputs = new char[] { 'X', 'W', 'U', 'T', 'R', 'Q', 'P', 'N', 'M', 'L', 'K' };
        }
        else
        {
            outputs = new char[] { 'R', 'Q', 'P', 'N', 'M', 'L', 'K', 'X', 'W', 'U', 'T' };
        }

        return last == outputs[total % 11];
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

And again in PHP

```
function isNricValid ($theNric) {

    $multiples = array( 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 );

    if (!$theNric || $theNric == '')
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (strlen($theNric) != 9)
    {
        return false;
    }

    $total = 0;
    $count = 0;
    $numericNric = 0;

    $first = $theNric[0];
    $last = $theNric[strlen($theNric) - 1];

    if ($first != 'S' && $first != 'T')
    {
        return false;
    }

    $numericNric = substr($theNric, 1, strlen($theNric) - 2);

    if (!is_numeric ($numericNric)) {
        return false;
    }

    while ($numericNric != 0)
    {
        $total += ($numericNric % 10) * $multiples[sizeof($multiples) - (1 + $count++)];

        $numericNric /= 10;
        $numericNric = floor($numericNric);
    }

    $outputs = '';
    if (strcmp($first, "S") == 0)
    {
        $outputs = array( 'J', 'Z', 'I', 'H', 'G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A' );
    }
    else
    {   
        $outputs = array( 'G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'J', 'Z', 'I', 'H' );
    }

    return $last == $outputs[$total % 11];

}

function isFinValid ($fin)
{
    $multiples = array( 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 );
    if (!$fin || $fin == '')
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (strlen($fin) != 9)
    {
        return false;
    }

    $total = 0;
    $count = 0;
    $numericNric = 0;
    $first = $fin[0];
    $last = $fin[strlen($fin) - 1];

    if ($first != 'F' && $first != 'G')
    {
        return false;
    }

    $numericNric = substr($fin, 1, strlen($fin) - 2);

    if (!is_numeric ($numericNric)) {
        return false;
    }

    while ($numericNric != 0)
    {
        $total += ($numericNric % 10) * $multiples[sizeof($multiples) - (1 + $count++)];

        $numericNric /= 10;
        $numericNric = floor($numericNric);
    }

    $outputs = array();

    if (strcmp($first, 'F') == 0)
    {
        $outputs = array( 'X', 'W', 'U', 'T', 'R', 'Q', 'P', 'N', 'M', 'L', 'K' );
    }
    else
    {
        $outputs = array( 'R', 'Q', 'P', 'N', 'M', 'L', 'K', 'X', 'W', 'U', 'T' );
    }

    return $last == $outputs[$total % 11];
}
```

Comment: What about NRICs starting with 'F' and 'G'?

Comment: NRICs starting with F & G (FINs) are covered under the isFinValid method.

Answer (score 6):

Here's similar code written in JavaScript

```
var nric = [];

nric.multiples = [ 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 ];

nric.isNricValid = function (theNric) {

    if (!theNric || theNric == '')
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (theNric.length != 9)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var total = 0
        , count = 0
        , numericNric;
    var first = theNric[0]
        , last = theNric[theNric.length - 1];

    if (first != 'S' && first != 'T')
    {
        return false;
    }

    numericNric = theNric.substr(1, theNric.length - 2);

    if (isNaN(numericNric)) {
        return false
    }

    while (numericNric != 0)
    {
        total += (numericNric % 10) * nric.multiples[nric.multiples.length - (1 + count++)];

        numericNric /= 10;
        numericNric = Math.floor(numericNric);
    }

    var outputs;
    if (first == 'S')
    {
        outputs = [ 'J', 'Z', 'I', 'H', 'G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A' ];
    }
    else
    {
        outputs = [ 'G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'J', 'Z', 'I', 'H' ];
    }

    return last == outputs[total % 11];

}

nric.isFinValid = function(fin)
{
    if (!fin || fin == '')
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (fin.length != 9)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var total = 0
        , count = 0
        , numericNric;
    var first = fin[0]
        , last = fin[fin.length - 1];

    if (first != 'F' && first != 'G')
    {
        return false;
    }

   numericNric = fin.substr(1, fin.length - 2);

    if (isNaN(numericNric)) {
        return false;
    }

    while (numericNric != 0)
    {
        total += (numericNric % 10) * nric.multiples[nric.multiples.length - (1 + count++)];

        numericNric /= 10;
        numericNric = Math.floor(numericNric);
    }

    var outputs;
    if (first == 'F')
    {
        outputs = [ 'X', 'W', 'U', 'T', 'R', 'Q', 'P', 'N', 'M', 'L', 'K' ];
    }
    else
    {
        outputs = [ 'R', 'Q', 'P', 'N', 'M', 'L', 'K', 'X', 'W', 'U', 'T' ];
    }

    return last == outputs[total % 11];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The below is the URL for NRIC & FIN algaritham.

http://www.arjun.com.np/blog/all-about-nric-number-in-singapore/

```
public class NRIC_FIN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String idNumber = "T123d121J";
        String NRIC = idNumber.toUpperCase();
        String number;
        int sum = 0;
        if (NRIC.length() != 9) {
            System.out.println("must be 9 digits..");
            return;
        }

        number = NRIC.substring(1, 8);

        if (!isNAN(at(number, 0)))
            sum += valueOf(at(number, 0)) * 2;
        if (!isNAN(at(number, 1)))
            sum += valueOf(at(number, 1)) * 7;
        if (!isNAN(at(number, 2)))
            sum += valueOf(at(number, 2)) * 6;
        if (!isNAN(at(number, 3)))
            sum += valueOf(at(number, 3)) * 5;
        if (!isNAN(at(number, 4)))
            sum += valueOf(at(number, 4)) * 4;
        if (!isNAN(at(number, 5)))
            sum += valueOf(at(number, 5)) * 3;
        if (!isNAN(at(number, 6)))
            sum += valueOf(at(number, 6)) * 2;

        if (NRIC.charAt(0) == 'T' || NRIC.charAt(0) == 'G') {
            sum += 4;
        }

        char checkChar = NRIC.charAt(8);

        double p = 11 - (sum % 11);

        if (NRIC.charAt(0) == 'S' || NRIC.charAt(0) == 'T') {

            if ((p == 1 && checkChar == 'A') || (p == 2 && checkChar == 'B')
                    || (p == 3 && checkChar == 'C')
                    || (p == 4 && checkChar == 'D')
                    || (p == 5 && checkChar == 'E')
                    || (p == 6 && checkChar == 'F')
                    || (p == 7 && checkChar == 'G')
                    || (p == 8 && checkChar == 'H')
                    || (p == 9 && checkChar == 'I')
                    || (p == 10 && checkChar == 'Z')
                    || (p == 11 && checkChar == 'J')) {
                System.out.println("true...NRIC");
            }
        }

        if (NRIC.charAt(0) == 'F' || NRIC.charAt(0) == 'G') {
            if ((p == 1 && checkChar == 'K') || (p == 2 && checkChar == 'M')
                    || (p == 3 && checkChar == 'L')
                    || (p == 4 && checkChar == 'N')
                    || (p == 5 && checkChar == 'P')
                    || (p == 6 && checkChar == 'Q')
                    || (p == 7 && checkChar == 'R')
                    || (p == 8 && checkChar == 'T')
                    || (p == 9 && checkChar == 'U')
                    || (p == 10 && checkChar == 'W')
                    || (p == 11 && checkChar == 'X')) {
                System.out.println("true ...FIN");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("flase ...");
    }

    public static boolean isNAN(char c) {
        return !Character.isDigit(c);
    }

    public static int valueOf(char c) {
        return (((int) c) - 48);
    }

    public static char at(String from, int index) {
        return from.charAt(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is for NRIC FIN check logic

Comment: checkout this [nric-lib github repo](https://github.com/mjallday/nric-lib) for the solution in multiple languages such as .NET, C#, Java etc.